# Can we compare LHS = RHS in query

Tags: database, oracle, csv, comparison

I have a query where I input username as a single string:

```
 'MONTY,JONTY'
```

My query part looks like:

```
SELECT *
  FROM tbl_dummy
 WHERE username IN (SELECT regexp_substr(:username, '[^,]+', 1, level)
                      FROM dual
                   CONNECT BY regexp_substr(:username, '[^,]+', 1, level) IS NOT NULL);
```

Here my column `'Username'` will have data like:

```
Monty, Jonty
Monty
Jonty
Jonty, Monty
```

So when I pass my string, it will split i.e `'Monty', 'Jonty'` and 
the query comparison will miss two values `"Monty, Jonty"` and `"Jonty, Monty"` out of 4 rows.

If i was able to split my column value while comparison, then i could have proved LHS = RHS.

So it would be `('JONTY','MONTY') = ('MONTY','JONTY')`

Is there any way this functionality can be achieved ? I cannot write stored procedure so it has to be an oracle query.

Also, Has anyone used RegExp_Like for such thing ? I am not able to find a syntax which would fit this code.

Comment: And why do you store multiple values in a single column? It violates normalization. It is a bad design. And this flaw would creep into more issues later. Performance issues are for sure.

Comment: which is your expected output in this case?

Comment: @LalitKumarB This is not my column format but there is a LISTAGG in inner query which joins the result and returns this columns. For some reasons I have to do a search in outer query only.

Comment: @Aramillo : It shouds return me all four compared rows. i.e 1- 'Monty, Jonty'
2- 'Monty'
3- 'Jonty'
4- 'Jonty, Monty'

Comment: @user1820973, then handle it before listagg is applied. You should mention these details in the question for an appropriate answer.

Comment: Sometimes we have to make the best of a bad design - even one that violates normalization - because it is already entrenched.

Comment: @user1820973, if you are aware of the values, just hardcode them using LIKE operator.

Comment: 'Monty, Jonty, Other' match with your conditions?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, and if your comma-delimited values aren't too long (regexes in Oracle are limited to 512 bytes IIRC), you can replace the comma-delimited list with a pipe (`|`)-delimited list and use `REGEXP_LIKE()' as follows:

```
WITH u1 AS (
    SELECT 'MONTY, JONTY' AS username FROM dual
    UNION
    SELECT 'MONTY' AS username FROM dual
    UNION
    SELECT 'JONTY' AS username FROM dual
    UNION
    SELECT 'JONTY, MONTY' AS username FROM dual
), u2 AS (
    SELECT TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR('JONTY, MONTY','[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)) AS username FROM dual 
    CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR('JONTY, MONTY', '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT * FROM u1
 WHERE EXISTS (
   SELECT 1 FROM u2
    WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(u2.username, '^(' || REGEXP_REPLACE(u1.username, '\s*,\s*', '|') || ')$', 'i')
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `LIKE` operator.

`where column_name like '℅MONTY℅' or column_name like '℅JONTY℅'`

You are trying to use `varying-IN` list in the predicate. In your case, `'MONTY, JONTY'` is a single `string`.

Comment: I am getting string from front-end. It is dynamic and not a fixed value. So next time it can be 'Monty' or 'Monty Jonty'

Comment: If you are sure about the two values then it would certainly work. If the number of values are non-deterministic, then it won't. And as I said, changing your table design is a better option.